# Migrate Identity Authentication from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application and I want to register and login using angular. I'm calling a Login and Register Method on my WebAPI when the user wants to Login/Register. The problem is that I don't know how to transfer my MVC Login and Register in the AccountController to my WebAPI.

My current Register method looks like this:

```
// POST api/RegisterApi
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]RegisterViewModel model)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       return await this.BadRequest(this.ModelState).ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken());
   }

   var user = new ApplicationUser
   {
       Email = model.Email,
       UserName = model.Email
   };

   IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

   if (!result.Succeeded)
   {
       return await this.GetErrorResult(result).ExecuteAsync(new CancellationToken());
   }

    // Auto login after register (successful user registration should return access_token)
    var loginResult = this.LoginUser(new LoginViewModel()
   {
       Email = model.Email,
       Password = model.Password
   }); 

    return await loginResult;
}
```

My main issue is the following line:

```
IdentityResult result = await this.UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

Somehow i can't call the CreateAsync-Method and I don't really know why.

I get the following error:

> Task' does not contain a definition for 'CreateAsync'
>   and no extension method 'CreateAsync' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'Task

Do you guys can give my any input on doing this properly? Everything I've seen so far seemed far too complicated for my problem.

EDIT: Okay the error is solved, but now there's a new problem. The CreateAsync method does not Create a User and returns to the error function in my AngularJs. Do you guys have any suggestion why CreateAsync could fail?

Comment: ah sorry, forgot about that, i'll edit it in the question

Comment: What is the type of `this.UserManager`?

Comment: In the WebAPI Controller-Class: public Task<IdentityResult> UserManager { get; private set; }

Comment: UserManager should be type of `UserManager<TUser, TKey>`

Comment: Okay yeah, that works but now the user is not created and it returns to my error function in angular, do you have any idea why that could happen?

Comment: @FKutsche There is not enough detail, and the question is to complex for stack overflow. Here's a good guide http://proudmonkey.azurewebsites.net/asp-net-5-jump-start-to-angularjs-with-mvc-6-web-api/

Comment: I found that link earlier, but there is no problem with Angular, it's just the registration, the User is not created at that line